# Why was I temporarily blocked from Facebook for liking 5 statuses?

Tags: facebook

Yesterday I went to reply to a comment and was told I was temporarily blocked, I can't remember exactly what the message said but after regaining access to my account it told me my account may have been used by spammers and it told me to check my activity log.

What confuses me after looking at my activity log is that the day before I got blocked I only liked 3 pictures, liked one post and commented on one post.

My password is a 50 character, secure password, I have 2 step verification turned on, I don't 'like' any pages and don't click dodgy looking links so my account can't have been compromised, especially being as 2 step verification is enabled.

Can someone shed some light on this for me? I know I was only 'temporarily blocked' but does anyone know how many times you can get blocked before your account is permanently blocked or deleted? I'm worried about using the service now as I don't want to get my account permanently banned or deleted.

Comment: That's definitely strange as there are plenty of "serial likers" out there who will like every single thing that shows up in their feed, and they never get blocked.